# Calculation is not working

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I made a calculator but only an addition operation is working.

Here is code

```
            <form>
            <input type = "text" name = "num1"/>
            <input type = "text" name = "num2"/>
            <select name = "opr">
            <option>Add</option>
            <option>MULTIPLY</option>
            <option>SUBTRACT</option>
            <option>DIVIDE</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <button type ="submit" name ="submit" value = "submit">submit</button>
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET['submit']))
            {
            $num1 = $_GET["num1"];
            $num2 = $_GET["num2"];
            $opr =  $_GET["opr"];

            if($opr = "ADD")
            {
                $num3 = $num1+$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            elseif($opr = "MULTIPLY" )
            {
                $num3 = $num1*$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            elseif($opr = "SUBTRACT" )
            {
                $num3 = $num1-$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            else{
                $num3 = $num1/$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            }

            ?>
```

I also made a conditional statement for other operations too but now sure why it's not working. I am trying to get values from URL using a $_GET function. But only ADD method is working.

Comment: `=` - This is not how you compare in PHP.

Comment: And after that `Add != ADD`.

Comment: Comparison is == not =

Comment: But addition is working using following code 

other cases are not working

Comment: Because it's the first case.

Comment: Because `$opr = "ADD"` is always true as it's assigning ADD to `$opr`.

Comment: Because is like comparing booleans, that's why goes in the first condition..

Comment: Although my question got -2 :(  I know its easy one but I am newbie to this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` instead of `==` to check the condition.
I have updated your code . Please find as below.

```
<form>
            <input type = "text" name = "num1"/>
            <input type = "text" name = "num2"/>
            <select name = "opr">
            <option>ADD</option>
            <option>MULTIPLY</option>
            <option>SUBTRACT</option>
            <option>DIVIDE</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <button type ="submit" name ="submit" value = "submit">submit</button>
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET['submit']))
            {
            $num1 = $_GET["num1"];
            $num2 = $_GET["num2"];
            $opr =  $_GET["opr"];

            if($opr == "ADD")
            {
                $num3 = $num1+$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            elseif($opr == "MULTIPLY" )
            {
                $num3 = $num1*$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            elseif($opr == "SUBTRACT" )
            {
                $num3 = $num1-$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            else{
                $num3 = $num1/$num2;
                echo $num3;
            }
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @ Eugene Sh-Yes , I have checked it is working for me.

Comment: Even the "Add"? I would say it is going to divide instead.

Comment: @TanujVerma- Thanks , mark the answer right if it helps you.